# Camera not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, android-context

I have MainActivity in which I have all the function related to camera. 
When I am calling the camera open function from mainactivity is working fine. But when I am calling the main activity camera function through adaptor it is giving below error:-

> 1-10 15:53:48.494 5741-5741/user.com.test2 E/InputEventReceiver:
>   Exception dispatching input event. 11-10 15:53:48.494
>   5741-5741/user.com.test2 E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue
>   callback: handleReceiveCallback 11-10 15:53:48.494
>   5741-5741/user.com.test2 E/MessageQueue-JNI:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
>   android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3794)
>                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
>                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3755)
>                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
>                                                                       at user.com.hlthee.Reminders.galleryIntent(Reminders.java:1049)
>                                                                       at user.com.hlthee.Reminders$24.onClick(Reminders.java:1033)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1082)
>                                                                       at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
>                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
>                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3072)
>                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3920)
>                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3657)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8476)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2400)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2093)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2372)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
>                                                                       at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:765)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
>                                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8671)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4171)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4037)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3587)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3606)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3723)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3614)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3780)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3587)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3606)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3614)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3587)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5855)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5829)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5800)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5945)
>                                                                       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>                                                                       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
>                                                                     at androi 11-10 15:53:48.494 5741-5741/user.com.test2 D/AndroidRuntime:
>   Shutting down VM

Calling from adaptor:-

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MedicineAdaptor.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        holder.ReminderCardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                Log.i("On Long Pressed","Yes");
                //Toast.makeText(context,Integer.toString(listMedicine.getId()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Creating the instance of PopupMenu

                final PopupMenu popupMenu=new
                        PopupMenu(context,holder.ReminderCardView);

                //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reminder_options,popupMenu.getMenu());

                //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener

                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){


                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        if (item.getTitle().equals("Edit Details"))
                        {


                            //Edit details
                            //((AddReminder)mactivity).openDialogToAddReminder();
                            Reminders reminders=new Reminders();
                            reminders.openDialogToAddReminder(context, dbHelper, listMedicine.getRemender_id(),listMedicine.getId());

                            update(listMedicine);

                        }                      

                        return false;
                    }
                });

                popupMenu.show(); //showing popup menu


                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void cameraIntent(Context context)
    {
        Intent takingPictureCameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        **if (takingPictureCameraintent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)**
            startActivityForResult(takingPictureCameraintent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
```

logcat is showing the error at highlighted line above:-

**Research done:-** From what i able to figure out using google and stackoverfollow. It is because of context.

so I tried
context.getPackageManager()

but by doing this camera is not working in mainActivity also.

Edit:--

Mainactivity.java

```
  public void openDialogToAddReminder(final Context context, final DbHelper dbHelper, final int Rem_id, final int Med_id) {

 LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.add_reminders_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.myDialog));

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(mView);

        captureImage = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.capture_image);
        captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImage(context);
            }
        });


          alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(dialog_title, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   }

                   })
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();


 }



 public void selectImage(final Context context) {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery",
                "Cancel" };

        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result= Utility.checkPermission(context);

                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent(context);

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Choose from Gallery";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent(context);

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


public void galleryIntent(Context context)
    {
        Log.i("Context ",context.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }

    public void cameraIntent(Context context)
    {
        Intent takingPictureCameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takingPictureCameraintent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager())!=null)
            startActivityForResult(takingPictureCameraintent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }

    public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data)
    {
        try{
            Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            Log.i("Image Camera Bitmap ",thumbnail.toString());

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90,bytes);

            captureImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            saveToGallery(thumbnail);
        }
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }
```

Updated:-

```
public void cameraIntent(Context context)
    {
        Intent takingPictureCameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (context.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ListReminders"))
        {
            context.**startActivityForResult()** // bolded region is red color. means no fuction found. 
        }
        else
        {
            if (takingPictureCameraintent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager())!=null)
                startActivityForResult(takingPictureCameraintent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }

    public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data)
    {
        try{
            Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            Log.i("Image Camera Bitmap ",thumbnail.toString());

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90,bytes);

            **captureImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);** // getting nullpointerexception
            saveToGallery(thumbnail);
        }
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }
```

Comment: Please, provide more code. more adapter code and mainactivity code.

Comment: I have added mainactivity code @Vyacheslav

Comment: @Vyacheslav I have updated the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31059575/1979882 read this answer

Comment: I have read the answer and apply the changes.. Since my activity which is calling adapter class is different with the activity of whose function I am calling so getting the error. activityOne cannot be cast to mainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give try to this.
Since you are calling the `cameraIntent` from adapter class. and in this method the `startActivtyForResult()` is method of activity class. You need to call `context.startActivtyForResult()` instead of calling `startActivtyForResult()` when you are calling from adapter.

You can achieve it by adding a `callType` parameter in the `openDialogToAddReminder`.

```
if(callType.equals("fromActivity"))
{
    startActivtyForResult(....);
}
else
{
    ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult();
}
```

Comment: since you are calling the cameraIntent from adapter class. and in this method the startActivtyForResult() is method of activity class. you need to call context.startActivtyForResult() instead of calling  startActivtyForResult()  when you are calling from adapter.

Comment: if(callType.equals("FromActivity"))

Comment: I think fromactivity means the context info that I am sending to mainactivity.. I have tried using below method:  class which is calling adaptor is, lets suppose listreminder and I called the opendialogAddreminder from the adaptor and pass the context.  Now I have try if(context.getclass.getSimpleName.equals("listreminder){ context.startActivityFor Result()}  here I am not getting red line at startAcitivityForResult means no function found

Comment: no . it is just callType that you can pass while calling the openDialogToAddReminder method. if you are calling the openDialogToAddReminder then pass the fromActivity else pass the callType fromAdapter or anything that you want

Comment: fromActivity= calling method from mainActivity itself and fromAdapter =  calling method from adapter. sorry for bad explanation

Comment: sorry bro. I didn't get you.. please at my comment above

Comment: here I am not getting red line at startAcitivityForResult means no function found

Comment: i didn't get u. are you getting this function or not?

Comment: I have update my question. with the error.  I am not getting function

Comment: ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult();  you will get the function

Comment: I got another error while testing the this feature so unable to check weather this working or not. In preview the captured Image . captureImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);  here it is giving null point exception

Answer (score 0):

Did you have insert the permission for camera into the `Manifest.xml`?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```