# Attempting to go from a class to an activity

Tags: java, android-intent, android-activity

I was getting the error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
```

So I tried to follow the directions in this [Android: Null Pointer Exception when calling new intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059390/android-null-pointer-exception-when-calling-new-intent)

But I just end up getting a new error, this is what leads up to the error

> GameplayScreen

```
if(gameOver && event.getX() > 50 && event.getX() < 250 && event.getY() > Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT-150 && event.getY() < Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT-50){
     if(context instanceof StartGameActivity){
          ((GameplayScene)context).endActivity();
     }
}
```

> StartGameActivity

```
 public void endActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(StartGameActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

> Full error

```
2019-08-17 14:58:15.146 7674-7674/com.example.tmd.mygametrue E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2019-08-17 14:58:15.146 7674-7674/com.example.tmd.mygametrue E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-08-17 14:58:15.148 7674-7674/com.example.tmd.mygametrue E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.tmd.mygametrue.StartGameActivity cannot be cast to com.example.tmd.mygametrue.GameplayScene
        at com.example.tmd.mygametrue.GameplayScene.recieveTouch(GameplayScene.java:196)
        at com.example.tmd.mygametrue.SceneManager.recieveTouch(SceneManager.java:19)
        at com.example.tmd.mygametrue.GamePanel.onTouchEvent(GamePanel.java:56)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-08-17 14:58:15.148 7674-7674/com.example.tmd.mygametrue D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-08-17 14:58:15.150 7674-7674/com.example.tmd.mygametrue E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tmd.mygametrue, PID: 7674
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.tmd.mygametrue.StartGameActivity cannot be cast to com.example.tmd.mygametrue.GameplayScene
        at com.example.tmd.mygametrue.GameplayScene.recieveTouch(GameplayScene.java:196)
        at com.example.tmd.mygametrue.SceneManager.recieveTouch(SceneManager.java:19)
        at com.example.tmd.mygametrue.GamePanel.onTouchEvent(GamePanel.java:56)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Sometimes the code in `GameplayScreen` works, but only once then it crashes again

Also, some things to remember is that this isn't an activity to an activity, its a java class to an activity.

Comment: Is `GameplayScene` an Activity? Does the class `GameplayScene` include the method `endActivity()`?

Comment: At the bottom, it says ```GameplayScreen``` is a class. Also right above the ``endActivity()``` function, it says it's from an activity called StartGameActivity @BenjyTec